# Select rows where field matches one of several thousand strings

Tags: mysql, r, select, rows, org-mode

I want to select all the rows in a table that have a particular field property. Namely the field is one of a hundred thousand strings that are known.

I'm using R to send the query. So I have code which looks like:

```
my_samp <- sample(unique_ids, replace=T, size=10^6)  
my_conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(),user='me',dbname='my_db')
query <- paste('SELECT blah1, blah2,...,blah900 FROM my_table WHERE      blah1=',paste(my_samp,collapse=' OR ',sep=''),sep='')
res1 <- dbSendQuery(my_conn, query)
my_data <- fetch(res1,n=-1)
dbDisconnect(my_conn)
```

However, I fear that the string won't be processed correctly by either the R interpreter or mysql. I also suspect that this is inefficient. Is there a cleaner solution?

I can't read the whole table directly into R with dbReadTable as it's too big.

I'm planning to do this several thousand times by forking the process - statistical bootstrapping.

There need to be duplicate records in the query if the string is repeated in my_samp.

Comment: Does this work as-is (assuming a smaller data-set, fewer criteria)? If so, this may be better for CodeReview.SE

Comment: Your table has 900 columns? Seriously?

Comment: May be a dumb question: can you upload your search strings to the database?

Comment: @BlueMagister - Not dumb, he does say they are known, which to me would mean the are defined well before query execution. A join on good indexed fields is probably the only efficient way of doing this.

Comment: @ Gaffi: Yes, it works with smaller criteria and data. Thanks, I'll look at CodeReview.

Comment: @MarkByers-Yes, there are 900 columns, the table can't be normalised.

Comment: @BlueMagister and InvertedSpear, thanks that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to:

1. A) Create a subquery that creates that list of known strings or B) Insert the known strings into a table on the database
2. Then A) create a new join query with those tables or B) use the ["IN clause"](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm) with an immediate list as in:

   ```
   query <- paste('select * from my_table where blah1=',paste(my_samp,collapse=' OR ',paste(' in (str1, str2, str3, str4)',sep=''),sep=''),sep='')
   ```

Comment: This would not work so well. The way MySQL works it would run that subquery for every row in the table like what happened here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782979/does-mysql-optimize-subqueries-automatically/11783170#comment15651895_11783170 A join is going to be much better than using in()

Comment: unless the in clause is given an immediate example that doesn't need to be queried from the database like in my example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this too. It's my preferred solution. I just don't know if it will like being given a hundred thousand strings.

Comment: @BryanWolfford - Sorry, your example wasn't there when I commented.

Answer (score 1):

As per Blue Magister's Line of thinking, you should probably have a table with all of these "known" strings stored in it. Then you can join to that table in a query to filter out your results.

Comment: This might work. My worry is blowing size of my ibdata1 file beyond the 1TB I have provisioned as I keep inserting and deleting the "known" strings table - I could store the string table as a separate file with a soft-link to another storage device if this becomes a pain. But I won't know until I start the process.

Comment: @Yoda Just out of curiosity, why would you be inserting and deleting these strings repetitiously? If they are known, why would the list not be somewhat stable?

Comment: They are known for each iteration. I need to fork the process and run models on each of the queries in R - it leads to smoother fits. sample() is a volatile function, so the strings change at each call.

Comment: I just realised that there need to be replicates in the query, if they are in the strings. Thanks for the question invertedSpear.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to create a temporary table in the database, you can populate it with all your strings and then join to it when selecting rows.  If it's more permanent than that, maybe you can create the table and manage the strings inside the database instead of R.